# Subharmonic functions in the unit disk

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I want to prove this:

Let $u$ be a function defined in the unit disk $D$, which is strictly subharmonic, i.e. $\nabla^2u>0$. Show that $u$ cannot have a maximum in $D/\partial D$.

I'm trying to prove it by contradiction, and I think that I need the fact that if the hessean is negative at a point, then this point is a maximum. However having a maximum doesn't imply that the hessean is negative. So how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The eigenvalues of the Hessian are the principal curvatures of the function, which imply maxima when negative and vice versa.
Maybe that will help? I'm also trying to prove this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).